# Does Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation has a bug?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, navigation, bug

Magento 1.7.0.2. I don't use flat category/products structure.

Take a look at file app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Navigation.php.

function **_renderCategoryMenuItemHtml**:

```
// get all children
if (Mage::helper('catalog/category_flat')->isEnabled()) {
     $children = (array)$category->getChildrenNodes();
     $childrenCount = count($children);
} else {
     // category is instance of Mage_Catalog_Model_Category
     $children = $category->getChildren(); // return string
     $childrenCount = $children->count();
}
```

function **getChildren** of Mage_Catalog_Model_Category object:

```
/**
  * Retrieve children ids comma separated
  *
  * @return string
  */
  public function getChildren()
  {
      return implode(',', $this->getResource()->getChildren($this, false));
  }
```

The question is - how we can call $children->count() if $children is a string? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. If the flat category is not enabled then the `$category` var you have in the block you specified is not an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`. It's an instance of `Varien_Data_Tree_Node` and the method `getChildren()` looks like this:

```
/**
     * Retrieve node children collection
     *
     * @return Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection
     */
    public function getChildren()
    {
        return $this->_childNodes;
    }
```

I know it doesn't say much but in the comment you can see it returns an instance of `Varien_Data_Tree_Node_Collection` that has a `count()` method...so everything is OK.
And by the way, in CE 1.7+ this block is not used anymore. This is used to add the categories to the menu: `Mage_Catalog_Model_Observer::addCatalogToTopmenuItems()`.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding PHP's `implode` will return a string.

> Returns a string containing a string representation of all the array elements in the same order, with the glue string between each element.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

If your wanting a count, `explode` the returned imploded value from `getChildren()` and then count the array elements.

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: I understand that, but these are magento core files. So this is magento bug.... And I didn't find any information about this bug and that is strange...